# How to merge with SVN server prior to 1.5 (retrieval of mergeinfo unsupported)?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Locally I've got `TortoiseSVN` version 1.6.11 installed.

This is using Subversion 1.6.13

My central SVN repository uses version SVN Server version 1.4.2 (and I can't upgrade it).

Every time I try to merge I get the message:

```
retrieval of mergeinfo unsupported by http://svn01.xxx.xxx.com/svn/
```

This is because the server uses an older version of SVN, which doesn't support mergeinfo, meaning my local version won't work.

So how can I merge?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When merging, >=1.5, clients can do merge-tracking - basically find the revision when the last merge was done. Merge-tracking information is stored in the svn:mergeinfo property by the client when it performs a merge and once the merge is done, it is stored by the server. So when a new merge is done, the client expects to get this mergeinfo from the server.

In older servers, you have to explicitly mention the revision that you last merged ( or branched)

```
svn merge svn://server/repo/trunk@revision svn://server/repoo/branch .
```

Or use older client.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know what the equivalent GUI command is in TortoiseSVN?

Comment: Works great, thanks!
I'm using TortoiseSVN 1.5.8, SVN server 1.6.2. Tried to reintegrate a branch, and got the "retrieval of mergeinfo unsupported" message. Running command-line 'svn merge' with the last trunk-to-branch merge revision solved the issue.

Comment: It's worth noting that finding the revision is easier using Tortoise SVN's "Revision Graph"